# batch file to monitor folder and copy images locally

Tags: windows, batch, pictures

Looking for a batch file to run on a windows scheduled task to:

1. Check a network location for images
2. If there are pictures to copy, copy them to a local folder
3. Delete the pictures from the network location

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Understand what you want to do, but details would be great. Do you control this folder? Are you or someone else placing the pictures in the folder? Are they a specific file type; gif, jpeg, tiff, png, ect?

Comment: I control both folders. Someone else is placing the photos in the network location. They are all .jpg 's

Answer (score 2):

In powershell, run the following:

`$a = get-childItem network_location -recurse -include *.gif,*.jpg`

`move $a local_location_here`

If you want other extensions, just add them to the list.

To create a powershell script, just open a txt file and then save it with a .ps1 extension.

Comment: Can you run this from task scheduler in windows 2008 server?

Comment: what is $a suppose to equal? Path to the jpg? never used powershell

Comment: got this to work. Dumb question, how do I create a powershell script to run?

Comment: Shouldn't this be "move" in order to meet the third requirement?  Or do a delete upon successful completion of the copy?

Comment: @nkuebelbeck, see edit, Paul you are correct.

Comment: @nkuebelbeck Just for explanation, `$a` holds all of the objects that are returned by get-childItem (in this case files). Move then moves the files.